# Data Structure - Create java objects for easy access in data table

Tags: java, data-structures

**Table - A**

```
ID      Country         State       City        Level           Count
1       2               2           1           A               153 
2       2               2           1           B               1232
3       2               2           1           C               125
4       2               2           1           D               15
5       1               1           3           A               123
6       1               1           3           B               1654
```

And I have respective tables for Country, State, City and Level

**Country**

```
ID      Country_Name
1       India
2       USA
3       Australia
```

**State**

```
ID      Country_ID      State_Name
1       1               AP
2       2               NJ
3       2               NY
```

**City**

```
ID      State_Id        City_Name
1       2               Newark
2       2               Jersey City
3       1               Delhi
```

**Level**

```
Id      Level_Name
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
```

I have my UI representing the above table as follows -

```
Country [2]
    State
        City
            Level - A       153
            Level - B       1232
            Level - C       125
            Level - D       15

Country [2]
    State
        City
            Level - A       123
            Level - B       1654
```

The tree is pretty much multi-level but the only data that can be modified in count. How can I create my java objects to make it easy to represent on the UI? Country, State, City are all collapsible.

Environment # JDK 1.6, Spring MVC, Jquery

Comment: Why not make all the objects be a row in the datatable, and then when it comes to making collapsable do a dictionary/Map where the key is the Country and the Value being the array of objects associated with that country.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [DefaultTreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html). The options are children of the previous option. You would have to create a function that creates the tree from the parent id values.

Comment: may I forgot to mention that I want this structure to be used by a web application. Does this work?

Comment: I don't know how you are implementing the web application, but I think you can use data structure classes, just not GUI classes.